# MbUnit: The most elegant way to compare doubles?

Tags: mbunit, gallio

The code

```
Assert.AreEqual (9.97320998018748d, observerPosition.CenterLongitude);
```

produces

```
Expected Value & Actual Value : 9.97320998018748
Remark : Both values look the same when formatted but they 
are distinct instances.
```

What is the most elegant way to compare two doubles for equality in MbUnit 3.0? I know I could round them up myself, but is there some MbUnit construct for this?

UPDATE: I consider my current "workaround" to be non-elegant:

```
Assert.LessThan(
   Math.Abs(9.97320998018748d - observerPosition.CenterLongitude),
   0.0000001);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`AreApproximatelyEqual`](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_AreApproximatelyEqual.htm) seems to be the "MbUnit construct for this":

> Verifies that an actual value
>   approximately equals some expected
>   value to within a specified delta.

This seems to be similar to [`Assert.AreEqual(double expected, double actual, double delta)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243458.aspx)