# C#, NUnit: Is it possible to test that a DateTime is very close, but not necessarily equal, to another?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datetime, nunit

Say I have this test:

```
[Test]
public void SomeTest()
{
    var message = new Thing("foobar");
    Assert.That(thing.Created, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.Now));
}
```

This could for example fail the constructor of Thing took a bit of time. Is there some sort of NUnit construct that would allow me to specify that the `Created` time don't have to be *exactly* equal to `DateTime.Now`, as long as it for example is within one second of it?

*And yes I know constructors are not supposed to take much time, but just as an example :p*

Comment: wanna switch to mbunit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727260/mbunit-the-most-elegant-way-to-compare-doubles ;-)

Comment: Comparing DateTimes using the local timezone is a bad idea. It can fail if the time zone changes (due to summer time). Use DateTime.UtcNow instead.

Comment: not really. not now anyways. in the process of learning nunit and writing tests in general, so one testing framework at a time will do :p also, nunit have something similar for floating point numbers.

Comment: @Mark: Isn't the time zone kind of unlikely to change in a single test run though?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but according to [the docs](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=equalConstraint&r=2.5.2) it looks like this should work:

```
Assert.That(thing.Created, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.Now).Within(1).Minutes);
```

I can't say I'm normally much of a fan of the constraints system - I'm an `Assert.AreEqual` fan - but that particular construct is rather neat.

(As a point of principle I should remark that you'd be best off passing some sort of "clock" interface in as a dependency, and then you wouldn't have any inaccuracy. You could fake it for the tests, and use the system clock for production.)

Comment: ooh, nice :D These constraints just keep surprising me... Is there a nice guide that walks through all of these with some good usage examples? (Other than the manual, which is pretty good too)

Comment: Can't say I know much about them myself. I just looked up the docs when I saw your question, hoping there'd be a nice simple solution. I was expecting to have to take the ticks and form an approximation that way - I was very pleased when I saw the "minutes" property.

Comment: Yes. These constraints are better for verify precision in numbers, for example Assert.That(actualResult, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult).Within(0.00000001).Percent);

Answer (score 2):

Check out the TimeSpan object - compare both dates using TimeSpan and check to see if the values are within your threshold.

```
TimeSpan span = thing.Created - DateTime.Now;
if(span.TotalSeconds <= 1)
   [..]
```

Comment: You want to use TotalSeconds Seconds get you the seconds component so if the span is 61 seconds total, this would pass your check.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder - I remember making this mistake while working with TimeSpan quite a while back. :)

Comment: (The Seconds instead of TotalSeconds bug that is...)

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to start out by defining "very close". If by "very close" you mean a few hundred ticks then you could do this:

```
Assert.That(200, Is.LessThanOrEqualTo(DateTime.Now.Ticks - thing.Created.Ticks));
```

Then whenever you've got dates within 200 ticks your test passes.

Comment: ... so long as it doesn't decide to create it in the future, of course.

Comment: Use the absolute value Math.Abs(DateTime.Now.Ticks - thing.Created.Ticks)

Answer (score 1):

You could check subtract them and check the timespan.

```
        DateTime.Now.Subtract(thing.Created).TotalSeconds
```

Gives you the totalseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can always subtract DateTime variables and you get TimeSpan. With Time span you can do whatever you want.